# Why am I getting error line 83: [: : integer expression expected for the following code

Tags: bash, scripting

```
populateNumbersArray() {
    declare -ai numbers
    ## error on the following line
    while [ "$counter" -lt $numNumbers ] && [ -z ${numbers[$counter]} ] || [ "${numbers[$counter]}" -le 0 ]
    do
        read -p "Please enter number $counter (1 or bigger): " numbers[$counter]
        if [ "${numbers[$counter]}" -le 0 ]
        then
            echo -e "\nIncorrect input. Please try again\n"
            sleep 1
            clear
        else
            setCounter
        fi
    done
    printNumbers numbers[@];
}
```

I have tried quotes around the var names, etc. The code still runs fine, but I'd like to eliminate the error message.

Comment: What's in `$counter` and `${numbers[counter]}` at the moment of the error? (Try `set -xv`)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R: its the only one with a comment.

Comment: `[ -z $unquoted[variable ]` does not work correctly when the variable is actually empty. In that case it evaluates to `[ -z ]` which, contrary to the intended goal gets handled by test as `[ '-z' ]` which is seen as `[ -n '-z' ]` and passes as a non-zero-length string.

Comment: counter is 0 when this func is run. ${numbers[$counter]} is undef.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to initialize the value of `counter` prior to the while loop (and probably to zero). Even though there is little practical difference between an unset variable and a variable whose value is the empty string, the `[` command does not treat the empty string as 0 when it comes to the various comparison operators (`-lt`, `-le`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

`[ -z $unquoted[variable ]` does not work correctly when the variable is actually empty.

In that case it evaluates to `[ -z ]` which, contrary to the intended goal, gets handled by test as `[ '-z' ]` which is then handled as `[ -n '-z' ]` and the test passes since `-z` is a non-zero-length string.

At which point the last test in the line will be evaluated as `[ "" -le 0 ]` which has an empty string in an integer context and generates your error.

Comment: I have tried it like this:  [ -z "${numbers[$counter]}" ] and I get the same error....

Comment: `X && Y || Z` in the shell is *not* a ternary operation. If *either* `X` *or* `Y` fails then `Z` will be run. So you will also incorrectly hit the last test when your loop finishes and `$counter` equals `$numNumbers`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the ternary comment from Etan, I solved my problem thusly:

```
populateNumbersArray() {
    declare -ai numbers
    while [ "$counter" -lt $numNumbers ]
    do
        while [ -z "${numbers[$counter]}" ] || [ "${numbers[$counter]}" -le 0 ]
        do
            read -p "Please enter number $counter (1 or bigger): " numbers[$counter]
            if [ "${numbers[$counter]}" -le 0 ]
            then
                echo -e "\nIncorrect input. Please try again\n"
                sleep 1
                clear
            fi
        done
        setCounter
    done
    printNumbers numbers[@]
}
```

Comment: `X && { Y || Z; }` would also have worked to enforce grouping.

Comment: Note that `X && Y || Z` is a common idiom for a compact version of `if X;then Y;else Z;fi`. Eg `[ 15 -gt 10 ] && echo y || echo n` prints `y` and `[ 5 -gt 10 ] && echo y || echo n` prints `n`.